# How to decipher font encoding & install LaTeX font for use in MacWord?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

I want to know the font being used in my document. I saw on other posts that this can be determined using the following command:

```
   \showthefont
```

I also found LaTeX font encodings here: [http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/encguide.pdf](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/macros/latex/doc/encguide.pdf)

When I compiled, this is what was given:

```
\T1/lmr/m/n/12
```

I understand 12 is referring to 12pt font size. However, I don't know how to interpret this output any further.

I want to know precisely what font is being used, because I am typesetting my references in Mac Word 2011 so I want to use the same font used elsewhere. This stems from difficulty in LaTeX formatting issues of the references section to meet my university's thesis requirements.

Comment: `lmr` is the "latin modern" font family; `m` is "medium" weight, and `n` is "normal' (upright) shape.  there's some possibly useful information in table 7.3, p.346, in the latex companion.

Comment: `\showthefont` is not a standard command you can use `\expandafter\show\the\font` or `\showthe\font` (the first gives more information)

Comment: @ David The first command provides:`T1/lmr/m/n/12=select font ec-lmr12` . Translated with both (@ Barbara, @David) your help, "latin modern" font family, "medium" weight, and n "normal" shape.  This lends itself to another question: Can this be duplicated in a word processor? Or by downloading fonts that can be accessed by a word processor (i.e., Mac Word 2011).

Comment: I found this `fonts/tfm/public/lm/ec-lmr12.tfm` here: (http://ftp.math.utah.edu/pub/tex/historic/fonts/latin-modern/lm-0.993/MANIFEST.txt). Unsure how to leverage this information however.

Comment: If you are running TeXLive, you can find the fonts in Open Type format in the TeXLive directory under `texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm` and there `lmroman12-regular.otf`. This font can be installed on OS X and subsequently used with programs like MacWord.

Comment: @ Christian. Ok, definitely still learning the command line. But I'm there now: `texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm`  I can see `lmroman12-regular.otf` listed. Ok my inexperience will definitely show with this next question.. How does one go about and install this font on OS X via command line?

Comment: I moved `lmroman12-regular.otf` to my Desktop using basic unix commands `cp` and `mv`. On the Desktop, double-clicked it and installed the font. I'm looking at it --- it's beautiful. Now just need to figure out how MacWord can access it.

Comment: Hurray! A simple restart of the computer and I now have access to Latin Modern Roman 12 Regular in MacWord. Next time that should go faster... :-)

Comment: Why don't you do the references in LaTeX? Even if you can't format them automatically, surely typesetting them by hand in LaTeX would be preferable to doing them in Word?

Comment: I compiled them in LaTeX, but cannot get specific formatting that I need (e.g. two inch margin for first page, 1 inch margin for subsequent pages; also a triple space after `REFERENCES'). I was using apa6 document class and it seems that it doesn't work with the titlesec package, which might have more control. As is, I'm just copying the references and pasting them in MacWord (now have the font I need). Then just merge the documents with Adobe Pro at my university.

Answer (score 1):

@Barbara & @David showed me to decipher the font.

```
`\expandafter\show\the\font`
```

and font was `\T1/lmr/m/n/12=select font ec-lmr12`

@ Christian Lindbig pointed me in the correct direction to install this for MacWord to find. It just took me awhile to actually execute it...

In the terminal:

```
`cd ~`
`cd ../../..`
`cd ./usr/local/texlive/2014/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm`
```

The font I want: `lmroman12-regular.otf`

```
 `cp lmroman12-regular.otf ~`
 `mv lmroman12-regular.otf Desktop`
```

Double click the font, click install, and restart the computer. Now "Latin Modern Roman 12 regular" font is available to me in MacWord.